# Getting instance of an object from child fragment by parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Problem:**

i have a `layout` like this:

[image]

in the `parent fragment` i have a `searchview` responsible for `filtering` the `recyclerviews` inside the `child fragments`.

the `child fragments` are inside a `tablayout` `viewpager` combination.

so the `OnQueryTextListener` is inside the `parent fragment` and i have to get an instance of the `recyclerviews adapters` from child fragments to do the filtering.

what is the proper way to do this?

**What I've tried:**

i searched and found `getChildFramgentManager` which returns an `instance` of the `child fragment`. but apparently, the fragments should be created dynamically? im not sure how that works with  `viewpager`. so if there is a way to do this with `getChildFramgentManager` and `viewpager` please explain.

**My code:**

everything I've written is the standard procedure and im not that far into the project to add something that changes the outcome so im not gonna take your time by adding the code, but if the code is necessary please say so and i will add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your viewpager's adapter you can store references to child fragments into a list and iterate through child fragments to call a method.

Something like this :

**Parent fragment**

```
class ParentFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_fragment, container, false)

        val search : SearchView = findViewById(R.id.search)
        val pager : ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager)

        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        pager.adapter = adapter

        search.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                adapter.filter(query ?: "")
                return true
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        })

        return view

    }

}
```

**Pager adapter**

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

    private var mList : MutableList<ChildFragment> = ArrayList()

    init {
        mList.add(ChildFragment())
        mList.add(ChildFragment())
    }

    fun filter(text: String) {
        mList.forEach {
            it.filter(text)
        }
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return mList.get(position)
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mList.size
    }

}
```

**Child fragment**

```
class ChildFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_fragment, container, false)

        // get reference to recyclerview, set adapter...

        return view

    }

    fun filter(text: String) {
        // do job here
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry im not new to android, how should i make viewpager refresh every time a search query is submitted?